# How to copy a preloaded sqlite database into the documents directory?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am preloading an sqlite database and then bundling it into another project along with the exact same data model that was used to created the sqlite database. 
The code for my managedObjectContext:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataModel", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Error getting data model url from the main bundle!")
        }
        guard let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initiating the data model!")
        }
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
        var documentsDirectory = urls[0]
        let dataStoreURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite")!, to: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite"))
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!, to: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite-shm"))
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!, to: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite-wal"))
        } catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError(error.debugDescription)
        }
        do{
            let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: dataStoreURL, options: nil)
            let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
            context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            return context
        } catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError("Error adding persistent store at \(dataStoreURL): \(error)")
        }
    }()
```

When I run the project I get this error:

```
reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store
```

I used the exact same data model; how can it be incompatible?

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Update: I found that the problem, I trying to copy the preloaded sqlite database into the documents directory even if one already existed in the first place. I added a condition to only copy over the database from the main bundle to the documents directory on the first run if the database does not exist. The updated code is as follows:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        //**********************Getting Data Model********************************
        guard let dataModelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataModel", withExtension: "mom") else {
            fatalError("Failed to get data  model URL from main bundle!")
        }
        guard let dataModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: dataModelURL) else {
            fatalError("Failed to initiate data model from the main bundle!")
        }
        //**********************Getting persistence store*************************
        let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let dataStoreURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite")
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataStoreURL.path){
            let sourceSqliteURLs = [Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite"), Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite-shm"), Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DataStore", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")]
            let destSqliteURLs = [documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite"), documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite-shm"), documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("DataStore.sqlite-wal")]
            for (index, sourceURL) in sourceSqliteURLs.enumerated() {
                do{ try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL!, to: destSqliteURLs[index])
                }catch{
                    fatalError("Error while copying data store files from main bundle to the documents directory!")
                }
            }
        }
        do{
            let persistenceCordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: dataModel)
            try persistenceCordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: dataStoreURL, options: nil)
            //*******************Initiating managed object context******************
            let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
            context.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistenceCordinator
            return context
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error.debugDescription)
            fatalError("Error initiating managed object context!")
        }
    }()
```

Comment: There's almost certainly more to that error. Core Data usually gives a lot of detail on this, and that detail would be critical to fixing the problem.

Comment: @TomHarrington I found the source of the problem. I updated the post above.

Comment: @A.Jam: Can you please translate your source to objective c?

Comment: @RonWood I'm sorry I don't speak Objective-C. I can explain what the code does if that helps?